# Sending pre-minified/pre-gzipped CSS and JS to the browser

Tags: .htaccess, gzip, minify

I have automatic way of minify/gzip JS and CSS during deploy on the server. Files are really lite. Now I'm having a problem, browser doesn't read it. I've tried something like this in .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch .*\.min.css.gz>
ForceType text/css
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch .*\.min.js.gz>
ForceType text/javascript
</FilesMatch>
```

What I have to do to make it work and not to infect on slowing server down?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure it, here is the solution:

```
AddEncoding gzip .jsgz .cssgz
AddType application/x-javascript .jsgz
AddType text/css .cssgz

RewriteEngine on 
# If client accepts compressed files 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip 
# and if compressed file exists 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}gz -f 
# send .min.cssgz and .min.cssgz instead of .css and .js
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(min.css|min.js)$ $1.$2gz [L]
```

For some reason file_name.min.css.gz is not working, so solution with file_name.min.cssgz is working great. I hope that this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

For some using [this PHP library](https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify)
You can name your files as `file.min.js` or `file.min.css`.

In your `.htaccess` all you need if following code.

```
AddEncoding gzip .js .css
```

and everything should be working fine.

NOTE: comment the `.htaccess` code share above, when you are not using minified/gzipped files.